# Getting number of gps weeks for given dates

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, timedelta

I have the following Pandas Series and would like to get number of GPS weeks for that dates:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
times = pd.Series([Timestamp('2015-11-27 00:00:00.540000'), Timestamp('2015-11-27 00:00:00.699000'), Timestamp('2015-11-27 00:00:01'), Timestamp('2015-11-27 00:00:01.699000'), Timestamp('2015-11-27 00:00:02.699000')])

In [116]: times
Out[116]:
0   2015-11-27 00:00:00.540
1   2015-11-27 00:00:00.699
2   2015-11-27 00:00:01.000
3   2015-11-27 00:00:01.699
4   2015-11-27 00:00:02.699
Name: GMT, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

When I'm trying to substract date for the beginning of GPS epoch and get total seconds I've got:

```
gps_epoch = datetime.datetime(1980, 1, 6)
delta = times - gps_epoch

In [120]: delta
Out[120]:
0   13109 days 00:00:00.540000
1   13109 days 00:00:00.699000
2          13109 days 00:00:01
3   13109 days 00:00:01.699000
4   13109 days 00:00:02.699000
Name: GMT, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I'm trying to map `total_seconds` for that series hovewer I've got an error:

```
In [124]: delta.map(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

But when I'm trying to get total seconds of the first element everything is fine:

```
In [130]: delta[0].total_seconds()
Out[130]: 1132617600.54
```

Then for getting number of GPS weeks I could do following:

```
In [135]: np.floor(delta[0].total_seconds()/86400/7)
Out[135]: 1872.0
```

I've checked types for both cases and they are different..:

```
In [137]: type(delta[0])
Out[137]: pandas.tslib.Timedelta

In [138]: delta.map(lambda x: type(x))
Out[138]:
0    <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
1    <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
2    <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
3    <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
4    <class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
Name: GMT, dtype: object
```

The question why it's not working with `map` method and why types are different?

Comment: Doesn't `delta.dt.total_seconds()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do [`dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html#pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds):

```
In [67]:
delta.dt.total_seconds()

Out[67]:
0    1.132618e+09
1    1.132618e+09
2    1.132618e+09
3    1.132618e+09
4    1.132618e+09
dtype: float64
```

and:

```
In [68]:
np.floor(delta.dt.total_seconds()/86400/7)

Out[68]:
0    1872
1    1872
2    1872
3    1872
4    1872
dtype: float64
```

Or use `floordiv`:

```
In [84]:
delta.dt.total_seconds().floordiv(86400).floordiv(7)

Out[84]:
0    1872
1    1872
2    1872
3    1872
4    1872
dtype: float64
```

The error occurs because the `dtype` is converted to a `np.timedelta` which has no `totalseconds` attribute whilst a pandas `timedelta` does (as it subclasses `datetime.timedelta`)  see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html

Consider the following:

```
In [97]:
type(delta[0])

Out[97]:
pandas.tslib.Timedelta

In [100]:    
delta[[0]].map(lambda x: print(type(x)))

<class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
Out[100]:
0    None
dtype: object
```

This is probably done to provide compatibility with `np` methods but you can use `dt.totalseconds` as a convenience routine

Comment: It works, thanks. I missed that functionality. But it's still interesting about type conversions do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: Unsure, I'm trying to figure this out

Comment: This maybe an issue with `np.datetime64` module version, mine is `1.9.3` and if I do this `d = np.datetime64('2009-01-01') - np.datetime64('2008-01-01')
d.totalseconds()` I get the same error

Comment: my numpy version is `1.10.1`

Comment: Actually isn't this something to do with the fact that pandas `Timedelta` subclasses python `datetime.timedelta` and is compatible with `np.timedelta` which has no `totalseconds` attribute but `dt.timdelta` does? See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html and also this code works: `d = dt.datetime.now() - dt.datetime(2015,1,1)
d.total_seconds()`

Comment: So the `dtype` gets converted to `np.timedelta64` using `map` but you have no `totalseconds` attribute when this happens, but if you access a specific scalar value then it remains a pandas `Timedelta` which does

Comment: You are probably right. But I thought `map` method access directrly to each value instead of `apply` which for whole Series. If so it should access as Pandas `Timedelta`. Is it correct?

Comment: `apply` would fail here also, `apply` is also a `for` loop it just allows you operate either column-wise or row-wise when called on a df, the type conversion is being doing by pandas here